# Encoding issue when upgrading from Websphere 7 to Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, encoding, websphere, ibm-was

We recently moved an application from WAS 7.0 (on AIX) to WAS 8.5.5 (on Linux). It interfaces with a couple of applications that send data in the form of an xml

The XML is retrieved from the header using -

```
while ((i = request.getReader().read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
            sb.append(buf, 0, i);
        }
```

However after transition, we noticed that the application was not handling special characters like **è** or **©** correctly - they are garbled.

This looks to me like an encoding issue. Can anyone point on what needs to be checked to understand the root cause?

I was reading further on this and i see that I can set the JVM arguments to

`-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8`

to always use UTF-8. Is this a good practice?

**Edit**:

```
Locale output in Linux

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Locale output on AIX
LANG=en_US
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

One application sends the xml as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` and the other sends it as `<?xml version="1.0">`

After setting the above mentioned JVM setting, the `<?xml version="1.0">` is treated correctly but the one with the encoding set to ISO-8859-1 is not. I am totally lost here.

Comment: You should use a hex-viewer to exactly decide what 'garbled' means, eg 'I expected code 0xE8 for (C) symbol but got 0x9E)'

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you application is not written to use a specific encoding and therefore uses the default of your session.

Check on AIX and Linux the locale with `locale`. On Linux it might be something like `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

To let your application behave on Linux the same as on AIX set on Linux the locale to the same value as on AIX.

Using unicode aware applications is not a bad idea in general. But there are exceptions where you need to stick to another encoding, e.g. LATIN-1 for some legacy systems. Then in your code you explicitly need to choose this encoding where it is needed.